# How can I find the text between two colons

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, hue

New to SQL and learning as I go.

How can I find the text between 2 colons in SQL on HIVE?
 E.G.

```
Text 1: hello:ok:old:yes:age:
Text 2: hello:no:old:yes:hour:
Text 3: hi:fine:old:yes:minute:
```

I want to find the text that is always coming after ":old:yes:" until the next :

```
Output 1 = age
Output 2 = hour
Output 3= minute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 options

```
hive> select regexp_extract('hello:ok:old:yes:age:','([^:]+):$',1);
OK
age
```

---

```
hive> select split('hello:ok:old:yes:age:',':')[4];
OK
age
```

Comment: How would the regexp_extract change if this data was in a column named "pages" and I want for every row that has ':old:yes:' to return the string after 'yes:' and before the next string  


PAGES (table name)
hello:ok:old:yes:age:test:jack
hello:no:old:yes:hour:black:nancy
hi:fine:old:yes:minute:white:jason

As you can see ':old:yes:' is my starting point and i want the regexp_extract to return the next text before the colon. In the above example I would want the following results:

age
hour
minute

Comment: Will do - thanks for the help. 
FYI - here the link to the new question, if you can help :)
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863025/extract-data-from-a-string-sql)

Answer (score -1):

You can also use patindex start from that position until the next charindex for :

Answer (score -1):

Try this

it should be work

```
select SUBSTRING('hello:ok:old:yes:age:', CHARINDEX('old:yes','hello:ok:old:yes:age:')+8, LEN('hello:ok:old:yes:age:') - CHARINDEX('old:yes','hello:ok:old:yes:age:')-8);
```