# Extract data from a string sql

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

How would the regexp_extract change if this data was in a column named "pages" and I want for every row that has ':old:yes:' to return the string after 'yes:' and before the next string?

**PAGES (table name)**

```
hello:ok:old:yes:age:test:jack   
hello:no:old:yes:hour:black:nancy   
hi:fine:old:yes:minute:white:jason
```

As you can see ':old:yes:' is my starting point and i want the regexp_extract to return the next text before the colon. In the above example I would want the following results:

```
age  
hour  
minute
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  regexp_extract(page,':old:yes:([^:]+)',1)
from    pages
where   page like '%:old:yes:%'
```

---

```
+--------+
| age    |
| hour   |
| minute |
+--------+
```

Comment: Can you help with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370135/how-to-remove-duplicates-while-doing-count-distinct-in-hiveql